# How do I secure API flask in order to be only consumed for my frontend app?

Tags: api, security, flask, oauth, single-page-application

I created an API using flask_restjsonapi, I want to integrate the API where it can only work with my future reactjs frontend(the application is an E-commerce, the API is the backend which is representing the app datalayer). I expect that a user could access the products data without being authorized (as a guest), but it certainly needs to be logged to access to a pay view or for buying something. So how could I get this? Oauth (which flow type), basic authentication, cookies. Which steps do I follow?

PS: I'm kind of new in Reactjs and API security.

Comment: maybe you need to work with `jwt ` tocken (https://jwt.io/introduction/), this package may be useful for your case https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, do not implement your own security (I do not think you indent to do that reading your question, this is for completeness).

Then start by reading the [OWASP REST Security Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html). It will give you an overview of what to be ready for.

Once you understand what the various elements are for, implement them using a library for your language. Again, do not try to roll your own version - libraries will be way faster and way, way more secure.

> I want to integrate the API where it can only work with my future reactjs frontend

This is not possible (the *only* part). If you have an API, anything can connect to it if it knows how to do that. Do not try to make it a secret (this is called *"security by obfuscation"* which may or may not be a useful idea, but certainly never a security solution on its own)